# Azure Storage Webhook being triggered by historical events

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions, webhooks

I have an Azure Function which uses the webhook bindings to be triggered by each upload or modification of a blob in an Azure Storage container.

This seems to work fine on an empty test container, *i.e.* when uploading the first blob or modifying one of two or three blobs in the test container.

However, when I point it towards a container with approximately a million blobs it receives a continuous stream of historic blob events.

I've read that

> If the blob container being monitored contains more than 10,000 blobs,
>   the Functions runtime scans log files to watch for new or changed
>   blobs.

[[source]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#trigger---polling-for-large-containers)

Is there any way I can ignore these historical events and consider only current events?

Comment: In your scenario, the Azure Event Grid (has been released for GA) should be solved this issue, where is not historical events.